# Why does vi-mode behavior differ between readline programs?

Tags: python, bash, sqlite, vi, readline

Specifically, the composition of number-delete-f/t-character gives different results in different programs.  On both osx/ubuntu, if I set in my .inputrc ...

```
set editing-mode vi
```

And then I open bash or sqlite3 and type "asdf asdf asdf" I can use the familiar bindings of vim's command mode: "2dff" to delete the first two words.

However if I have the same line in, say, the ipython interpreter or the R interpreter, this command doesn't work.  I do have *some* key bindings (e.g. typing "2dw" deletes two words).

Why is bash/sqlite3 editing differently than ipython/R?  I assume all four of them use readline.

Comment: `2dff`??? I just tried in vim and it doesn't work (it doesn't do anything as far as I can see). To delete two words `2dw` is **the** sequence. No idea why you call that the "familiar binding" (I'm not a vim poweruser, but I use vim mode in many editors and IDEs and I never used that kind of key sequence).

Comment: 2 means do twice, d means delete, f searches to a character, second, f is the character to search to.  Using three strings was an example, but sometimes I want to delete from the cursor to the Nth character (period).  Using 'w' to look for is quite useful (and also works everywhere) but this is more general.  The command works in stock vi, so I'm not sure why it wouldn't work in vim for you.

Comment: Ah, I thought you were saying that `2dff` deletes "the first two words" period. Which it doesn't.